# How can visualize text from input in table column jQUery?

Tags: jquery

I have table with folowing structure:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class='visual'></td>
    <td class='input'><input type='text' name='input-value' value=''/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class='visual'></td>
    <td class='input'><input type='text' name='input-value' value=''/></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td class='visual'></td>
    <td class='input'><input type='text' name='input-value' value=''/></td>
</tr>
```

I want after inserted text in input-value to display in td class='visual'

How can I do this with jQuery ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're trying to take text typed in the textboxes and put it in the table? Try this:

```
$(function(){
  $('[name="input-value"]').keyup(function(){
    var $this = $(this)
    $this.parent().prev().html($this.val())
  })
})
```